# Option method like `collect` that returns Unit?

Tags: scala, scala-option

Is there a method on the `Option` class that works like `collect` (it takes a partial function), but has a return type of `Unit`?

That is: `map` is to `collect` as `foreach` is to `?`.

Sorry, I'm new to Scala--I've looked over the `Option` docs and did a little research, but didn't find anything relevant.

I know I can just use `match`, I was just wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: what's your primary use case?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, I need to type cast a value `Any` to `String`, and then conditionally use that value to create a side effect (for a Java class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `collect` if your function returns a `Unit` and if it doesn't, don't hold on to it.

```
myOpt collect { 
  case x: Foo =>
}
```

no harm, no fowl if you discard the return.

Comment: okay, thanks, that seems fair. Quick question: in this case, why does `Option` need to have a `foreach`, when there is `map` available?

Comment: @kardeiz `foreach` makes it clear that you're executing a side-effecting function, where `map` does not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method for `Option`, and it's fine to let scala just discard the return value from `collect`, but if you *really* want a different method name, you can use an implicit conversion to enrich `Option`.

```
implicit class OptionExt[A](opt: Option[A]) {
    def forCollect(pf: PartialFunction[A, Unit]): Unit = opt.collect(pf)
}
```

(I have no idea what you'd really call this function.)

```
scala> Option[Any](1).forCollect { case i: Int => println("I'm an Int") }
I'm an Int

scala> Option[Any]("1").forCollect { case i: Int => println("I'm an Int") }

scala> Option[Any](None).forCollect { case i: Int => println("I'm an Int") }
```